# How to associate a "label" with each bit in an Erlang bitstring?

Tags: erlang, bit, bitstring

Suppose I have the following bitstring:

```
B = <<0:5>>.
```

Which contains five bits: `<<0,0,0,0,0>>`

To set one of those bits, I'm using this helper function:

```
-spec set(Bits :: bitstring(), BitIndex :: non_neg_integer()) -> bitstring().

set(Bits, BitIndex) ->
    << A:BitIndex/bits, _:1, B/bits >> = Bits,
    << A/bits, 1:1, B/bits >>.
```

I call the function like this:

```
B2 = bit_utils:set(B, 2). % Referring to a specific bit by its index (2).
```

Which will give me this bitstring: `<<0,0,1,0,0>>`

Is it possible to somehow associate a "label" with each bit in a bitstring?

Something like this: `<<A1=0,A2=0,A3=1,A4=0,A5=0, … >>`

So that I can refer to each bit by its label, instead of by its index as in the above function. By writing a function with a signature akin to this: `set(Bits, BitLabel)`.

Which could be called like this: `set(Grid, "A3")`

In my application, I'm using a fixed-size bitstring of 81 bits as a 9*9 "grid" (rows and columns). Being able to refer to each "cell" by its row/column identifier (e.g. `A3`) would be very useful.

Comment: you cant do that only with bitstrings. you have to use a helper key/value data type (e.g. map) with that bitstring. key can be label and value can be its index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't associate a label with a bit. Since the mapping between label and index seems to be fixed in your case, I'd instead create another function which maps the label to its index like this:

```
position(a1) -> 0;
position(a2) -> 1;
...
```

and then use that in `set`:

```
set(Bits, Label) ->
    BitIndex = position(Label),
    << A:BitIndex/bits, _:1, B/bits >> = Bits,
    << A/bits, 1:1, B/bits >>.
```

Now you can call `set/2` with an atom which is the label:

```
B2 = set(B, a1),
B3 = set(B2, c2).
```

Comment: That's a neat solution! Thanks for the advice. I was mucking around with the idea of using macros (e.g. `-define(a1, 0)`), but I think your solution is nicer.

Comment: Where does BitIndex come from in your function?

Comment: @7stud thanks, it was supposed to be `BitIndex =` not `B =`. I've fixed it!